# Trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.10 with Windows 10, last one not detected

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a laptop, and I'm going to install Ubuntu (I have experience, and I have  successfully installed [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux), Ubuntu, [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu), [Kubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu), [Manjaro Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro_Linux), etc.), but installing [Ubuntu 14.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.10_.28Utopic_Unicorn.29) (Utopic Unicorn) alongside [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10), Ubuntu can't detect Windows.

It shows me like there's no OS, but I have Windows 10.

I have two primary partitions by the way if I manually install. If the Ubuntu installer can't detect Windows 10, will it be detected at [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB)?

Answer (score 12):

I wasn't able to get the boot repair to work so I manually added a Windows 10 boot option.

The first step is to edit **/etc/grub.d/40_custom** (using SUDO) and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

In this case my bootloader was in **/dev/sda1** hence the 1 at the end of msdos. After this run **sudo update-grub2** and you should be good to go.

Worked for me, advice taken from here:
http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/

Comment: _Tip_: When using `grub-customizer` to create the GRUB2 menues (I do, just to have them neat `;)`), creating a chainloader type entry adds two additional lines to the two you had mentioned in the post. **Be aware to remove them, otherwise Windows 10 will refuse to boot** (It happened to me, so I spread the voice for solving the problem)

Answer (score 3):

Windows should be detected while you manually install Ubuntu 14.10 and added to GRUB. If it is not added initially, boot into Ubuntu, install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and run that. That should add Windows 10 to your GRUB.

Source: I have run a Windows 10, Ubuntu 14.10, elementary OS, Fedora quad boot

Comment: i will add solved to the tittle and apply this thanks

Comment: grub just show me w10 recovery and dont the normal start

Comment: Do you even have a Windows 10 recovery partiton. With some versions os-prober mis-identified Windows 7 boot and recovery, so maybe the same with Windows 10?

Comment: win10 clean install fela

Comment: @user284299 As you're a reputation 4 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)
(Don't add "Solved" to the title...  **;-)**)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Windows 7 after an Ubuntu 15.04 install.

The solution was to use Grub 2 ntloader module instead of chainloader.

Here is my 42_custom in /etc/grub.d/

```
menuentry "Win 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9804BD3004BD126C
ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
}
```

You can change the text to Windows 10, it's only text.

Comment: what does the string `9804BD3004BD126C` mean? I am getting weird errors relating to that...

Comment: A bit late to the party, but that's his partition UUID (They're short like that when windows sets them) And shouldn't the `set root=...` line be redundant since the `search` overwrites it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to run boot repair from the Windows 10 ISO image? That way, Windows will have an [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), and it would show the other operating systems. Try that.

I believe you have installed Ubuntu, so insert the Windows DVD and select repair -> *cmd*.

Now enter,

```
Bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

There are other commands too. You can try these out:

```
/FixBoot - writes a boot sector onto system partition to start Windows

/ScanOs - scans all disks for Windows installation and displays them.

/RebuildBCD - scans all disks for Windows installations and prompts you to pick the ones you want to add to the BCD.
```

Comment: it will show me ubuntu too?

Comment: You could try... It will install windows boot manager in MBR, if windows identifies the other OS, it should.

Comment: Windows boot repair ignores other OS systems

Comment: Windows does not recognize other OS. And if you screw up the repair by running fixmbr, there may be no turning back, unless of course you get super grub 2 installed from some other system and fix your ubuntu boot option at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Ubuntu and mount your Windows partition (simply open the disk on Nautilus)

Run the following on the command line: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>:

```
sudo os-prober
```

If your Windows installation was found, you can run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Note that step 2 is just for your convenience. You could just mount the Windows 7 partition and then run update-grub.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to describe what this code fragment means and what file it's found in (and what section)

Comment: I second @NickWeinberg not everyone will recognize that snippet as an entry in the grub.cfg file. Please expand your answer for the benefit of those who don't recognize it as those who do are unlikely to need the guidance. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: I found it in grub.cfg created by android installer. I'm not very good in editing grub (and english too...) but i think "root" and "chainloader" depends on localization of windows efi files.