# Shrink linux space to install windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gparted

I want to install windows while I have Ubuntu, but I can't figure out how to unmount `ext4` (the drive that contains linux) in order to shrink its space. Any ideas? I've been looking all around the internet for hours.

-if you didn’t understand:
my hard drive contains 950G (all of my space) and the used space is only about 30G,and I want to give Linux 200G free space. I tried gparted, but I cant unmount it, I tried unmounting through terminal and it is saying `device is busy`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this from within a running Ubuntu operating system.
The system and the swap partition must be mounted to work at all.

So you need a live media and do it from within there.
Boot from the Ubuntu (DVD/USB) installation media.

Select Try Ubuntu without installing, on Live desktop,
Open GParted - the partitions are unmounted - resize.

Note :

It is strongly recommended to first install Windows ... and after that Ubuntu.
When you do it the other way around you have to reinstall GRUB afterwards.

The way to do this depends on the partition table setup - msdos or GPT - of the disk being used.
When you installed Ubuntu in EFI mode, it is different from when installed in legacy BIOS mode.

How exactly to do this would be another question, but here you find : [all necessary instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683108/grub-menu-not-showing-at-boot/683119#683119).

**Anyway, please make sure you have a backup of everything, because  partitioning operation or an accidentally wrong decision during the system installation might damage your data !**

Answer (score 1):

To Shrink your Ubuntu Partitions you can use Ubuntu live CD, It has included the **GParted** partition editor, with its help you can modify your partitions.

**Note**: Please don't do this while it’s in use.

Download Link: GParted *http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php*

Download Link: *http://www.ubuntu.com/download*

Document: *http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-resize-partition*

Other partition tools can also usefull:

- fdisk
- gnome-disk-utility