# Problem with installing apps

Tags: software-installation

i Just joined to linux.

But i have a problem with app installing. i'm using mint 16. The first app i tried got installed but i get this warning during installing every other apps.

[image]

But i connected to the internet.

How can i fix it?

I got this when i'm trying to install via terminal

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

In addition, i can't install a new language. I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Could you try installing the app via the terminal ? Press `ctrl` + `alt` + `t` and type: `sudo apt-get install okular`. If you get any error there, please edit your question and add the logs from the terminal.

Comment: @SouravBadami i did it

Comment: @BD. so, have you solved your problem?

Comment: @ryanw NO. i got those errors...

Comment: @BD. -- I've added a solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that some old apt thread is locking the file. You need to find which process is using it and kill it. Follow this:

- Try to find which process is using `ps aux | grep apt`.
- Type, `kill -9 <processnumber>`.
- Update using `sudo apt-get update`.
- Install okular using `sudo apt-get install okular`.

If the method mentioned above doesn't work, try this:

- `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`.
- `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`.
- `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.
- Update using `sudo apt-get update`.
- Install okular using `sudo apt-get install okular`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: i got this after first command: 7306  0.0  0.0   4448   828 pts/0    S+   12:59   0:00 grep --colour=auto apt

Comment: What i type instead of <processnumber>

Comment: Use this instead: `killall -9 apt-get`. Although your process id is 7306.

Comment: apt-get: no process found

Comment: Maybe you could try the other method.

Comment: i got this: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8282500900/24.png

Comment: It appears that there's some issue connecting to the server. Could you try changing the server location from Software Sources ? Change the source for the base mirror.

Comment: How can i do this? it means i connect to some other networks?

Comment: Type `software-sources` in terminal. You can then select alternative servers for the repositories.

Comment: I traveled to Ubuntu and problem fixed. thanks a lot...

Comment: Hi. I installed windows after linux and grub are not loading. So how can I load ubunto?

Comment: Can you boot into windows ? If yes, then follow this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/683108/grub-menu-not-showing-at-boot.

Comment: Thanks. I reach my files using a Linux reader software throughout windows

Answer (score 1):

try run this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after that install your desired apps.

if not fixed try comment again here.

I hope it can help

Comment: I got a bunch of this error: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/inxi/inxi_1.9.12-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]