# Grub doesn't appear after installation - Windows boots automatically

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, hp

I have just bought an HP Z240 workstation, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu.

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.2 and installed it through its DVD, but after normally completing the install grub doesn't boot and only windows boot directly as before. I installed ubuntu alongside windows 10 (upgraded from windows 7).

In the BIOS I have "legacy enable secure boot disabled".

Comment: Do you have an EFI system partition?  What does `sudo parted -l` show?

Comment: Please visit this link, you may get your answer here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/683108/grub-menu-not-showing-at-boot-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-in-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks!!! The link solved my problem, i.e. boot repair installed the correct efi-I-don't-know-what for grub. But this only after disabling legacy boot from the "bios" (uefi?), so that uefi cdrom drive boot was enabled.