# Grub isn't displaying on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have Windows 10 installed in my laptop, and today I created a partition and installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop LTS.

Everything went well until the end of the setup process. Then I got a message telling me to reboot the computer and after rebooting, grub does not appear and even in the Windows bootloader I don't see Ubuntu as a choice. Windows are loading but I cannot access Ubuntu.

I've tried to use the following solution: [Grub menu not showing at boot after upgrading to Windows 10 in dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683108/grub-menu-not-showing-at-boot-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-in-dual-boot)
 and when I reboot the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! The page you linked contains several solutions. Have you tried all of them? What was the result of each? What is your [Boot-Repair URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Recommended_repair)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows 10, open a terminal with Administrator privileges and type

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Reboot