# How do I boot into Windows 10 again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, windows-10

I have windows 10 installed on partition 4 which is hibernated (but I'm able to mount it in read-only mode from Linux), but I cannot boot into it because I had removed the Windows bootloader. I also have Linux Mint 17.1 installed on partition 5 (into which I regularly boot). I need to boot into Windows 10 but I can't figure out how. I have tried lots of things including using boot-repair, adding menu-entries to grub's menu manually (as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564496/trying-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-14-10-with-windows-10-last-one-not-detected)), and some other things mentioned in Linux forums.

I have been searching for a solution for a long time. Lots of solutions include the usage of "Windows recovery disks" and/or usage of Windows software, however I can't do any of that. All I have with me is Linux Mint and a non-bootable but mountable Windows 10.

This is the output of `parted -l`

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  683MB   682MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      683MB   955MB   273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot
 3      955MB   1089MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      1089MB  861GB   860GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      861GB   863GB   1074MB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      863GB   970GB   107GB   ext4            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      970GB   971GB   867MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 7      971GB   1000GB  29.5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, msftdata
```

Edit: [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13328666/) is the new boot-info summary by boot-repair.

I have Grub bootloader currently which shows only the Linux Mint 17 entry. Any help will be greatly appreciated!