# Adding Windows to GRUB list after resizing partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

I had a dual boot on my PC with both Ubuntu and Windows 10. I had to extend my root partition since I was running out of space.

Here are the partitions before extending `/root/`

[image: gparted]

After expanding `/root`

[image: gparted]

I faced a GRUB failure and installed boot-repair through liveUSB by following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/), but GRUB is still not listing Windows.

The answers to these questions didn't help either:

- [Add windows to my boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110698/add-windows-to-my-boot-menu)
- [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Here is the result for `sudo update-grub`:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-87-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-87-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-86-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-86-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-85-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-85-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-83-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-83-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-79-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-77-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-71-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-67-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

What might be the way to add Windows to my GRUB?

Comment: I tried to edit the grub.cfg as answered in a link(i couldn't get it from my history), but could not make it work.

Comment: I tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/564496/trying-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-14-10-with-windows-10-last-one-not-detected and grub update throws error.
 "Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 1211
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done"